# Perform An Activity on Toast Disappear Event

Tags: android, toast

I want to populate a list after toast is disappear

I have a multiprocessing thing and in one method more around 10 toast is shown after doing something, i want to show in the list what is done what is not processed.

My problem is program runs at once and list will be populated as well. I want to show toast as it takes some delay than update list

Comment: This sounds like it would be better to use an `AsyncTask`. You can update as things are done using `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a Thread that lasts as long as the Toast is displayed and then you can do your work.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // your other stuff
            Toast.makeText(this,"This is a Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            thread.start();
}
```

Now create a thread that waits for (LENGTH_LONG = 3.5) or (LENGTH_SHORT = 2) seconds

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
             @Override
            public void run() {
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(3500); // As I am using LENGTH_LONG in Toast
                    Your_Activity.this.finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }  
           };
```

Comment: The Length may differ in different API versions.

Comment: First i will make sure that it will work fine and according to my requirements than i will Accept and Vote up Bro don't worry